# Run @AfterMethod only when my @Test is passed, not if @Test fails

Tags: java, selenium, testng

My `afterMethod` consists of this:

```
@AfterMethod(groups = { "Regression" })
public void afterMethod() {
    // Setting driver used to false as this test case is pass
    driverUsed.put("supportDriver", false);
    System.out.println("Test case is pass");
}
```

where I am putting the driver `false`

But I want to run this `afterMethod` only when my `@Test` is passed, not when `@test` fails.

Answer (score 10):

To quote [TestNG's documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection):

> Any `@AfterMethod` method can declare a parameter of type `ITestResult`, which will reflect the result of the test method that was just run.

You can use this parameter to check if the test succeeded or not:

```
@AfterMethod(groups = { "Regression" })
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
   if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        // Setting driver used to false as this test case is pass
        driverUsed.put("supportDriver", false);
        System.out.println("Test case is pass");
   }
}
```